# Why samba don't ask user and password when user and password are same on both side?

Tags: windows, samba, kerberos

I create a samba share like this

```
[test]
path = /data/test
valid users = test
read only = no
writable=yes
browsable=yes
```

then add user test and password test, if the computer use the same user and password, connect to samba will not ask for user and password.

I think the authentication is not plain text user and password, I don't expected macos or windows will save the clear text password, but how samba authenticate user ?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't expected macos or windows will save the clear text password,

That's actually what Windows does. As long as you're logged in, your Windows session will store an NTLM hash of your login password, and Windows will automatically use it when performing NTLM authentication against SMB servers.

(And yes, attackers have been known to steal password hashes this way – by tricking someone into connecting into a malicious SMB server.)

If the computer is on Active Directory, then additionally Kerberos tickets will be stored, allowing for much more secure authentication.

Comment: One reason Kerberos tickets offer additional security is due to them being time sensitive.

Comment: Does mac also save the NTLM hash ? I tried finder to connect smb, connected without asking user and password.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how macOS works in that regard. It _might_ be doing that. (Or it might even store the plaintext password? No idea.)